# Java how to get input for EditText from toggleSoftInput

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I created EditText by drawing it on canvas so I have problem on making the keyboard appear when clicked and to make the EditText receive input. After some searching, I found out that I can use InputMethodManager to make the keyboard appear to give inputs for EditText.

Unfortunately, EditText does not receive any character inputs from anything pressed on the soft keyboard.

And I need to use `imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);` because when I used `imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);`the soft keyboard did not appear at all when EditText is pressed.

Code:

```
if((int)event.getX() > 50 && event.getX()<400 && event.getY() > 50 && event.getY() < 200){
                editText.setFocusable(true);
                editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                editText.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
            }
```

How to solve this? Any working solution is welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: *I cannot use the usual xml EditText type* they are of the same type

Comment: umm I mean the usual ones when created, automatically able to make keyboard appear and receive inputs when clicked. Whereas in my problem I need to code it to have the same thing working. Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.

```
EditText edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.passwordtextvalue);
        edit.setOnKeyListener(this);

        InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        edit.requestFocus();
```

I have this in my app, and its working fine for edit text when I have the soft keyboard

Comment: 'this' in edit.setOnKeyListener(this) does not work for me, even though 'this' already refer to class that extends SurfaceView which is also a View. Any idea?

Comment: You can get the context by invoking getApplicationContext(), getContext(), getBaseContext()     Any one of this should definetly work

Comment: I think it works because you put it in Activity class? I run everything in a class called GamePanel class which extends SurfaceView. So, I need another way to call 'this' (neither getApplicationContext nor getContext work for me) Thanks for giving solution though

Comment: The thing here is , you just need the context  in that particular activity. You should get the application context somehow tere for it to work

Comment: usually I can just use getContext() to pass context. e.g. Toast.makeText(getContext(),...); But I don't know why it does not work for this one. Is there any other way to get the edittext hooked to the InputMethodManager ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: Umm as stated in my question, I have tried that way too but no keyboard showed up at all. If there is a method that takes editText as a parameter but still use toggle, I think it will solve the problem